# чем заменить depricated метод?

Tags: java

метод isEqualToComparingFieldByField чем можно заменить?

```
public static void assertMatch(Meal actual, Meal expected) {
        assertThat(actual).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(expected);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В javadoc [написано](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/blob/main/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.java#L419) использовать `usingRecursiveComparison`.